# What is the difference between $d$ and $\partial$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, derivatives

After seeing the following equation in [a lecture about tensor analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtPtxz3ef8U&t=1h30m10s), I became confused.

$$
\frac{d\phi}{ds}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^m}\frac{dx^m}{ds}
$$

What exactly is the difference between $d$ and $\partial$?

Comment: [Total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) vs [partial derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

Comment: @Jen, maybe elaborate a bit more in an answer? :)

Comment: I know, one is the partial and the other one is a total derivative. But isn't $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ the same as $\frac{df}{dx}$?

Comment: @iblue, the first one treats all the other independent variables as if they were constants. The second one doesn't.

Comment: @iblue Read what Jennifer linked to, it will help.

Comment: She edited her comment, and added the link to the wikipedia article on total deriviates. Now I see...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned $d$ means total and $\partial$ partial derivative and are not the same. Total derivative also counts $x$ dependencies in other variables. For instance:
$$
f(x,v) = x^2 + v(x) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = 1 \\
\frac{d f}{d x} = 2x + \frac{\partial v(x)}{\partial x} 
$$

Your formula most probably uses [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and is only a shorter way to write
$$
\frac{d\phi}{ds}= \sum_m \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^m}\frac{dx^m}{ds}
$$

Comment: Why it's partial dirivative of $v$ when you take derivative to $f$ ? is it suppose to be $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x + \frac{dv(x)}{dx}$  ?

Answer (score 19):

The difference is whether the *rest* of the variables of $f$ are considered constants  or variables  in $x.$ Former is partial, latter is total.

- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the [partial derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative): $f$ is differentiated w.r.t. to $x$ while *all* other variables are considered constants in $x.$
- $\frac{d f}{d x}$ the is [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative): $f$ is differentiated w.r.t. to $x$ while *nothing* is assumed about the other variables; they are considered variables in $x.$ (some variables might be, in fact, constants in $x.$)