# What is the difference between standard derivative and partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is actually a very old question that now I have to face it again and look for answer of it. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=y$ is a function. What is the difference between:

- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$
- $\frac{df}{dx_i}$ if this means anything at all?

I am reading this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486428818) and the following passage is part of the book:

> ...it would be appropriate to introduce a scaled time $\tau$ via
>
> $$\tau=\epsilon^2 t$$
>
> and regard $u$ as depending both on $t$ and $\tau$, and having no
>   explicit dependence on $\epsilon$; $t$ and $\tau$ will be treated as
>   mutually independent. Correspondingly, the time differentiation should
>   be transformed as
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}\to\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\epsilon^2
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} $$

Where $u=X-X_0$ and $X_0$ is a stable answer for following differential equation:
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=F(X)$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks. oops! I made a mistake in the denominator of the second one! It should be $\frac{df}{dx_1}$. Is that meaningful then?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, but if this limit is $\frac{df}{dx_i}$ what exactly is the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I am rally sorry I don't have my glasses and that was the reason I couldn't differentiate between $i$ and $1$. So based on what you are saying $\frac{df}{dx_i}\equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ ??

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't even realize you were using $d$ and I was too. $\frac{df}{dx_i}$ means nothing. All of my responses should have said $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$.

Comment: But then there is this book on Dynamical Systems that I am reading and actually approximates one of these based on the other. Let me edit my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $d$ and $\partial$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183325/what-is-the-difference-between-d-and-partial)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

Is a partial derivate so you suppose that all variables except $x_i$ are constant (you can this $f$ as a single variable function).

$$\frac{df}{dx_i}$$

Is a [total derivate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) (all variables may vary). So you have to apply the chain rule and  you get:

$$\frac{df}{dx_i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\frac{dx_j}{dx_i}$$

Comment: Thank you. Vote up. It kinda make sense but still I don't see how the limit base definition of this one is gonna look like?