# $dy$ by $dx$ or $dy$ divided by $dx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was always taught do not say "$dy$ divided by $dx$", instead "$dy$ by $dx$" because it's not really dividing.

I then studied differentiation from first principles, where one takes two points on a curve: eg. $(x, y)$ and $(x+\delta x, y+\delta y)$

$$\therefore \text{ gradient} = \frac{(y+\delta y)- y}{(x+\delta x) - x}$$

I'll skip the continuation but one gets the derivative of the equation through some algebra. If you simply expand the brackets instantly you simplify it to $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$ which is a division.

Firstly, why is the sign different - is it just because it is easier to right $d$ than $\delta$?

Secondly, why can one not say $dy$ divided by $dx$?

Thanks

Comment: $\delta y$ and $\delta x$ are finite, so they can be divided.  $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction -- we just use that notation because it behaves like a fraction in some formulas --, so it's not technically "$dy$ divided by $dx$", though of course, there is a division going on in the background (in the limit definition).

Comment: For the difference between $dx$ and $\partial x$ please see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/183330/90932

Comment: @DanielWilson-Nunn OP's not talking about the partial derivatives, he's talking about a finite change $\delta y$ along the tangent line.  So $\dfrac {\delta y}{\delta x}$ *is literally* a division of two finite numbers -- as opposed to $\dfrac {\partial y}{\partial x}$ which is just formal notation.

Comment: This might be interesting: http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/03/more-than-infinitesimal-what-is-dx/

Comment: $dy$ could mean the [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function), and in that context both $dy$ and $dx$ are finite numbers and could be divided. $dy=f'(x) dx= \dfrac{dy}{dx} dx$ so $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ ... could we interpret the two sides (of the latter) in a different way, e.g. as a fraction (LHS), or not a fraction (RHS), what would the equality mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

One can certainly **say** it.  The question is whether $dy$ and $dx$ actually mean anything by themselves, such that $dy/dx$ is their quotient.  And the answer is yes: they refer to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a displacement along the tangent line to the curve.

Comment: (...) an **infinitesimal** displacement (...)

Comment: No, **not** an infinitesimal displacement, an arbitrary displacement.  $dx$ is a new variable, and  $dy = (dy/dx) dx$.

Comment: It is critical here that the displacement is along the tangent line rather than along the curve itself.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, it obviously depends on which formalism you're using.  I think it would be better to use the notation $\delta y = \frac {dy}{dx} \delta x$  OR $dy = f'(x) dx$ to reduce ambiguity, but that's just my $2$ cents.

Comment: @Ian Okay this analogy will fail as soon as we go higher.

Comment: @Bye_World Usually $\mathrm d x$ is a short for the differential equivalent to the lebesgue measure in integration for the variable $x$, but getting that right is quite an advanced topic.

Comment: $dx$ means a whole bunch of related things in different fields. It has little to do with integration when it is used in differential geometry, for example.

Comment: @AlexR I haven't yet studied measure theory, but I have seen [this formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function), which seems to be the one that Robert is using here.

Comment: For reference, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) is the notation I refer to.

Comment: @AlexR I'm aware of differential forms, I've been studying differential geometry for a while now.  I just haven't done measure theory.  But differential forms are not infinitesimals (as your first comment would suggest).  And I'm still pretty sure Robert was using the definition from the Wikipedia article I linked to. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any harm in saying "$dy$ divided by $dx$".  But${}\ \ldots$

I was taught that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.
$$

Certainly $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ are numbers.

The differentials $dy$ and $dx$ are thought of as infinitely small but nonzero increments of $y$ and $x$.  This raises a question of whether one can really make sense of such a concept as infinitely small but nonzero quantities, and whether one can then do calculus with them, using them in just the way in which the notations $dy$ and $dx$ are used.  Robinson's nonstandard analysis does make use of infinitely small quantities, but not in just exactly the way in which Leibniz (who introduced the notation) and Euler (who used it more extensively than anyone else) used them.

The whole theory of calculus can be justified without proving that infinitely small increments can be taken literally.  That justification was done in the 19th century by "epsilons and deltas".

So the fact that one doesn't take them literally is why some people say you shouldn't speak of dividing when it's not clear that it's really dividing.

However, speaking of infinitely small increments is an immensely useful heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful, particularly once you start studying multivariable calculus, to recognize the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as not a real number but a linear map from tangent vectors on the domain to tangent vectors on the image.

From this, some misguided people get the impression that one "shouldn't" call $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in ordinary one-variable calculus a ratio. At a given value of $x$, tangent vectors $dx$ at $x$ and their pushforwards $dy$ can be canonically identified with real numbers, and the derivative of $y$ at $x$ ***is*** 100% rigorously the quotient $\frac{dy(dx)}{dx}$ (when $dx\neq 0$), which one can show does not depend on $dx$. As Robert points out, this has a very helpful and still 100% rigorous geometric interpretation when you intepret $y$ as a graph, and $dx$ and $dy$ as  infinitesimal horizontal and vertical displacements.