# Difference in use between $d$, $\partial$, $\operatorname d$, $\varDelta$ and $D$ for derivatives.

Tags: derivatives, notation, indefinite-integrals

While reading different sources on implicit differentiation (and thereafter differentiation in general), I came across many different "d's" being used for (or similar to) the familiar
$$\frac{dy}{dx}$$
The variant $d$ appears in the majority of cases, and also with integrals:

$$\int x~dx$$

Now, it appears like the convention on Wikipedia is to use $d$ or $\operatorname d$ for "normal" and $\partial$ for partial (which is also its name in Tex) derivatives. Is there an additional difference between $d$ and $\operatorname d$ (except the amount of characters needed), and are there any general conventions?

Comment: We might also throw in $\delta x$, used in (central) finite difference expressions.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183325/what-is-the-difference-between-d-and-partial?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I regard $d$ and $\rm d$ as the same. In general, I think of it like this:

- If $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, the *derivative* at $x$ is $f'(x)$ or $\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x}(x)$;
- If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, the $k-$th *partial derivative* at $x$ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(x)$, or $D_kf(x)$, or $D_{x^k}f(x)$, or $\partial_kf(x)$ or $\partial_{x^k}f(x)$;
- If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, the *total derivative* (Fréchet derivative, if you like it) at $x$ is $Df(x)$. In particular, we can call the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(x)$, which will be a vector whose components are the partial derivatives of the components, following the above item. If $f: \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^k$ we can also use $D_xf(x,y)$ and $D_yf(x,y)$ to denote blocks of $Df(x,y)$.  This is useful sometimes when doing things with the inverse/implicit function theorems.
- If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, the *differential* of $f$ at $x$ is the map ${\rm d}f_x: T_x\Bbb R^n \to T_{f(x)}\Bbb R^m$ given by ${\rm d}f_x(v_x) = (Df(x)(v))_{f(x)}$. Some people write ${\rm d}_xf$ instead of ${\rm d}f_x$.
- The *exterior derivative* of $k$-form $\omega$ is denoted simply by ${\rm d}\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

- $D_x$ is the same thing as $\frac{d}{dx}$, it's just a different **notation inveted by Euler.** The capital $D$ of course stands for derivative, and derivative is with respect to the "base" of $D$, for example $D_t$ is derivative in respect to $t$.
- $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a **partial derivative** used in **multi-variable calculus.** In this case, it is with respect to $x$, so other unknown variables other than $x$ would be set constant.
- $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$ is also not different from $\frac{d}{dx}$. Both d and $d$ are the same letters and I don't know why slanted $d$ would differ in any way from normal d. It is also used in integrals, as you said as d$x$ or $dx$, which is the **differential form**, and it is there *so you know with respect to which variable, should you integrate.*
- $\Delta x$ notes **change in $x$**, which is used in the definition of derivative for a point. The definition for derivative is:
  $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}f'(x)=\frac{f(x+ \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$ where, as I stated $\Delta x$ is change in $x$, which in calculation of derivatives, approaches $0$.

Comment: ...and $dx$ is a differential form - a 1-form. $dxdy$ a 2-form etc ...

Comment: ...and $D$ is also sometimes used to denote the gradient $\nabla$ or the material derivative
($\frac{D}{dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + y\cdot \nabla$).

Comment: ... $O(h)$ anyone?